# I/flutter (13707): │ getMyPoint type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int?'

Tags: flutter

Ok, so I've been trying to figure this out and so far I have this:

I added this code to output the issue on the console:

**This is the woo_commerce.dart:**

```
@override
  Future<Point?> getMyPoint(String? token) async {
    try {
      var base64Str = EncodeUtils.encodeCookie(token!);
      final response = await httpGet('$domain/wp-json/api/flutter_woo/points?token=$base64Str'.toUri()!);
      final body = convert.jsonDecode(response.body);
      checkExpiredCookie(response);
      print('Response: $body');
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        final point = Point.fromJson(body);
        print('Points: ${point.points}');
        return point;
      } else if (body['message'] != null) {
        throw Exception(body['message']);
      }
      return null;
    } catch (err) {
      rethrow;
    }
  }
```

**This is the point.dart:**

```
class Point {
  int? points;
  double? cartPriceRate;
  int? cartPointsRate;
  int? maxPointDiscount;
  int? maxProductPointDiscount;

  Point.fromJson(Map parsedJson) {
    points = parsedJson['points'];
    cartPriceRate = parsedJson['cart_price_rate'].toDouble();
    cartPointsRate = parsedJson['cart_points_rate'];
    maxPointDiscount = parsedJson['max_point_discount'];
    maxProductPointDiscount = parsedJson['max_product_point_discount'];
  }
}
```

and i got this:

```
I/flutter (13707): ┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
I/flutter (13707): │ 15:17:25.839 (+0:00:23.717674)
I/flutter (13707): ├┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄
I/flutter (13707): │ ! [⏰Medium-1950ms]♻️ GET:https://xxxxxxx.ca/wp-json/api/flutter_woo/points?token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
I/flutter (13707): └───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
I/flutter (13707): Response: {points: 6318, cart_price_rate: 1, cart_points_rate: 200, max_point_discount: 50000, max_product_point_discount: }
I/flutter (13707): ┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
I/flutter (13707): │ 15:17:25.895 (+0:00:23.773380)
I/flutter (13707): ├┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄
I/flutter (13707): │ getMyPoint type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int?' in type cast
I/flutter (13707): └───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
I/flutter (13707): ┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
```

Whats the issue? It was working for months, all of a sudden a customer said no points showing up on cart on the app..

I've tried everything within respect to my knowledge. I'm stomped.

Comment: How do you use `getMyPoint` func in your code?

Comment: import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../common/constants.dart';

import '../services/index.dart';
import 'entities/point.dart';

class PointModel extends ChangeNotifier {
  final Services _service = Services();
  Point? point;

  Future<void> getMyPoint(String? token) async {
    try {
      point = await _service.api.getMyPoint(token);
    } catch (err) {
      printLog('getMyPoint $err');
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

Comment: Check if the function getMyPoint(token) passed parameter token is of type int.

Comment: @harshbangari how do i do that?

Comment: Add .toString while passing parameter.

getMyPoint(token.toString)